# How to implement license serial number in android app

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I see some apps direct user to their website to buy a serial number from paypal, and some apps may need a username also.

Then user can return back to app and input the serial number and username if needed into to get some pro features like removing ads.

I want to do the same thing in my app, can someone help explain how to make it work ? is there any third part library to use?

To be clear, I do not want to use the in app purchase in google play.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own back-end that handles all transactions.
Then when the user has done a transaction your app will have to communicate with your back-end to confirm that the bought codes are correct. There is a lot of security that should be implemented aswell.

I would say that since you have to ask the question, you should use the in-app purchase in google play since its already implemented and streamlined.

Comment: thank you, but i think i do not need manage the transaction process, user just go to my website, click buy button, and get a code, and open my app. input the code into, app connect to server to verify it.

Comment: Well no, there is probably libraries from paypal and such that will help you with the transactions. But you will still need to have a secure protocol between your app and your backend. And you will need to store all informaion regarding what the users have bought. And of course implement the security around it so that this information will not leak or go missing.